# Count with Bresenham's line algorithm in real-mode,assembly

Tags: c, assembly, types, x86, floating-point

Hey!
I'd like to draw lines in assembly. I wrote the algorithm in C, now I need to put it into assembly.
I'm in 16bits real-mode; graphics-mode: 12h (640*480 16colors)
The C source:

```
//x1/y1/x2/y2 = start x, start y, end x, end y
void draw_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    double delta_l = (x2-x1)/(y2-y1);
         //delta_l = like graph slope; maybe it's negative and/or not integer
         // it can be also type 'float'
    double y;

    for(int x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
    {
        y = y1 + ( x * delta_l );
        Round_To_Integer(y);
        Put_Pixel(x, y, color);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't count with floating-point numbers (or double) in assembly.
Please help me to "translate" this C code into ASM.
Thank you.

Comment: just ask your compiler to output assembly if you've got the C code working already.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Optimization write in c, then cut it from generate asm code (no float's to care about)

Comment: Er...the whole *point* of Bresenham is that it works with *integer* arithmetic.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I misunderstood something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding of the Bresenham algorithm is that its core idea is to avoid floating-point arithmetic by using a variable where the error is summed up in an integer variable and a correction is made whenever the error exceeds a certain value.

This [page](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/bresenham.html) has a step by step explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use fixed-point arithmetic.  In real mode a pair of registers is used for the interpolated value.  Usually one contains the whole portion of the number and the other holds the fraction.  Use add with carry for each step.

Answer (score -1):

```
 MOV AX,0A000
 MOV DS,AX
 MOV AX,013    ; GRAPHICS MODE 13H 320X200
 INT 010
 MOV SI,0
 MOV CX,0
L4:
 MOV B[SI],31  ; DRAW PIXEL OF LINE 0,0 TO 320,200 USING BRESENHAM 
 ADD CX,200
 MOV AX,CX
 SHL AX,1
 CMP AX,320
 JB L5
 ADD SI,320
 SUB CX,320
L5:
 ADD SI,1
 CMP SI,64000
 JB L4
L2:
 MOV AX,0     ; HOLD SCREEN
 INT 016
 CMP AH,1
 JE L3
 JMP L2
L3:
 MOV AX,2     ; RESET MODE 2
 INT 010
 MOV AX,04C00 ; NORMAL EXIT
 INT 021
```